# Mongoose "or" operator not working as expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am attempting to combine two regex operators when querying my MongoDB, the second of which (id) being a number field, hence the weird conversions.

Both of these work individually, and if I replace the `$where` regex with a more traditional one, it also works, however when run as is, it only looks for records that match the `$where` regex

```js
this.Asset
  .find(query)
  .or([
        {
          name: { $regex: searchQuery, $options: "i" }
        },
        {
          $where: `function() { return this.id.toString().match(${searchQuery}) != null; }`
        }
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

`this.id.toString().match(${searchQuery}) != null || this.name.match(${searchQuery})`
?

Comment: Where would this be used?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try to debug the issue with `$where` because it is best to avoid using it if at all possible. The performance characteristics of using it really are not good for usage in production environments.

Instead, you can accomplish what you want via conversion operators in MongoDB directly. The [`$toString` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) is particularly relevant here. Assuming that `searchQuery` is `"123"`, one approach would be as follows:

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      name: {
        $regex: "123",
        $options: "i"
      }
    },
    {
      $expr: {
        $regexMatch: {
          input: {
            $toString: "$id"
          },
          regex: "123",
          options: "i"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JjdY6xEGkz3). Alternatively:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      idConverted: {
        $toString: "$id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          name: {
            $regex: "123",
            $options: "i"
          }
        },
        {
          idConverted: {
            $regex: "123",
            $options: "i"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "idConverted"
  }
])
```

[demo here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bARGZLKWpqr).

That said, even these approaches that avoid using `$where` are unlikely to be performant. Queries that filter on the transformed results are unable to use indexes efficiently. You may wish to look into other text searching approaches entirely for this to be usable by a production application.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. Unfortunately, even when adopting the `$match` format, I get the same behavior as in my question

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? Both of the playground demonstrations that I linked return the first two sample documents, one of which matches due to the string value for the `name` field and the other which matches due to the number value in the `id` field. Can you give a playground link or other details in your question that show otherwise?

Comment: I want the matching for both to be partial, like the name query, so if there are items with the ID 101, 102 and 103, a search for "10" will return all 3, that's why im choosing to use a regex and not an exact match

Comment: Can you help give a more specific example of how these approaches don't satisfy those requirements? [Here is a slightly modified playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gbc5ioGX52R) (just changing the stored values and the regex pattern) using data like you've provided where the numeric `102` in `ID` is returned successfully.